# how many normal operators $T$ that satisfy the following conditions are existing?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, normal-operator

Let $$T: V\rightarrow V$$  $\quad$ $$V=\mathbb{R^3}$$ given the following orthonormal basis with respect to an inner product space **(not the standard)** $$B=\{(1,1,1),(1,1,0),(1,0,0)\}$$
I am sked to find a normal operator with the following charachteristic polynomial $$f_{T}(x)=x^{2}(x-3)$$
and also $$\operatorname{ker} T=\operatorname{Span}\{(3,2,1),(2,1,1)\}$$

I am asking to find an normal operator $T$ that will satisfy those conditions, **and after that I am asked how many normal operators exists that satisfy those conditions.**

so the first part I succeded and I found that the represent matrix $A$ with respect to the orthonormal basis B is: $$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{3}{2}&0&-\frac{3}{2}\\ 0&0&0\\ -\frac{3}{2}&0&\frac{3}{2}\end{pmatrix}$$

Now I do not know how to answer the second part, how many of those exists? how should I think on such question?

Comment: You say "I found that the represent matrix $A$ with respect to the orthonormal basis B is...". How did you find this matrix? If you followed this process in a different way, would it be possible to produce a different matrix $A$?

Comment: I guess not but I am looking for a mathematical explanation, is the fact $T$ needs to be normal affect that? is the fact I was given charachteristic polynomial affect that?